# Foreach Loop in PHP only getting the first instance

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following code that was written to send an email reminder to users, but it only sends an email to the first user in the list and the remaining users are not emailed. The query does work in SQL to pull all of the users

```
$users = array(mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT wp_users.* FROM wp_users LEFT JOIN (SELECT lead_id, MAX(case when field_number = 7 then value end) AS email, MAX(case when field_number = 8 then value end) AS tournament_id FROM wp_rg_lead_detail GROUP BY lead_id) AS t1 ON t1.email = wp_users.user_email AND t1.tournament_id = '$tournament_id' WHERE t1.lead_id IS NULL AND id !=1")));


// Create the replacements array
$replacements = array();
foreach ($users as $user) {
$replacements[$user['user_email']] = array (
'{user_login}' => $user['user_login']
);
echo $user['user_email'] . "<br />" . $user['user_login']; 
}

// Create the mail transport configuration
$transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();

// Create an instance of the plugin and register it
$plugin = new Swift_Plugins_DecoratorPlugin($replacements);
$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
$mailer->registerPlugin($plugin);

// Create the message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance();
$message->setSubject("Pure Fantasy Golf Pick Reminder for {user_login}");
$message->setBody("{user_login}, this is a reminder that you need to submit a pick for this weeks tournament " . $tournament_name . ". Please go to http://dev.purefantasygolf.com to make your pick now.");
$message->setFrom("purefantasygolf@gmail.com", "Pure Fantasy Golf");

// Send the email
foreach($users as $user) {
$message->setTo($user["user_email"], $user["user_login"]);
$mailer->send($message);
}
```

Comment: var_dump($users), does this contain what you want?

Comment: you mean you did not even `print_r($users)` to see if you had all your rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation of [mysql_fetch_array](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array).

You need to loop over your results like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT wp_users.* FROM wp_users LEFT JOIN (SELECT lead_id, MAX(case when field_number = 7 then value end) AS email, MAX(case when field_number = 8 then value end) AS tournament_id FROM wp_rg_lead_detail GROUP BY lead_id) AS t1 ON t1.email = wp_users.user_email AND t1.tournament_id = '$tournament_id' WHERE t1.lead_id IS NULL AND id !=1");

$replacements = array();
while($user = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $replacements[$user['user_email']] = array (
        '{user_login}' => $user['user_login']
    );
    echo $user['user_email'] . "<br />" . $user['user_login'];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_fetch_array` does not fetch an array containing all rows. It fetches one row at a time in an array with the value in each column in an array element.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's a good idea to send N number of emails in loop. This could cause performance issues (if there is more than 10 users in mailing list). I think the better solution here is to add all users as BCC and send only one email.

Comment: Good idea, but it should be the `bcc` or you will have a serious issue with privacy protection.